# Is $H'(M) = 5M + 9H(M) \pmod{2^n}$ a secure hash function?

Tags: hash

> **theorem:** For arbitrary $i≥0$ there exists $m,n≥0$ such that $35+i=5m+9n$.

We can use this theorem for constructing simple hash function.

Let $M$ be message and $H(M)$ be its hashed value with hash function such as the $\text{SHA}256$. We construct new $n$ bit hash function $H'$ as follow:

> $H'(M)=5M+9H(M) \pmod {2^n}$

Is this hash function safe?

**Edit:** I want use this to compress $H$. So suppose that $n$ is smaller than bit size of $H$.

Comment: How is $H$ defined? I see a formal definition of $H'$ but not of $H$.

Comment: I don't think it's safe in general - the feed-forward of your hash (based on a variant of [Matyas–Meyer–Oseas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One-way_compression_function#Matyas.E2.80.93Meyer.E2.80.93Oseas)) could be constructed just so that it gets cancelled out.

Comment: Doesn't the extended euclidean algorithm solve your supposedly NP hard problem in polynomial time?

Comment: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diophantine_equation

Comment: I see. What's the purpose of this hash function if you need to assume a secure hash function for its construction?

Comment: @DrLecter It feels much as an exercise to me. It's about reasoning and finding a counterexample.

Comment: @Meysam Ghahramani: the question is interesting, but please fix the erroneous statement about NP-hardness.

Comment: If you want to shorten the output of $H$ why don't you simply truncate it? That's simple and secure for typical hashes.

Comment: @fgrieu, You are right. I edited my question.

Comment: is this question on topic her? I dont think so: [Do we accept questions asking for cryptanalysis of your cipher (hash function, ...) design?](http://crypto.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Consider

$$H(M)= 9^{-1} (E(M) - 5M) \pmod {2^n}$$

where $E$ is encryption using a random permutation with an efficiently computable inverse $D$. This is a secure hash for the same reason the  [Matyas–Meyer–Oseas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One-way_compression_function#Matyas.E2.80.93Meyer.E2.80.93Oseas) construction is.

Now using your definition of $H'$ we obtain:

$$H'(M)=5M+9H(M) = 5M + (E(M) - 5M) = E(M) \pmod {2^n}$$

Thus $M = D(H'(M))$ can be recovered and $H'$ is not a secure hash for all secure hashes $H(M)$.

Comment: @MeysamGhahramani I don't see how $\pmod {2^n}$ poses any problems. It just means that you need to compute $9^{-1}$ as the [Modular multiplicative inverse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_multiplicative_inverse), but that can be done efficiently using the  Extended Euclidean algorithm. The inverse exists since $\operatorname{GCD}(9, 2^n)=1$.

Comment: It is correct that you found $M$, but $M$ must be valid and its hashed value be coefficient  of $9$.

Comment: @MeysamGhahramani There is always exactly one solution for $M$ in $0 \le M < 2^n$. Multiplication with an odd constant is a bijection $\pmod{2^n}$.

Comment: I know this, but if original $M$ is larger than $n$ bit, your found $M$ is not valid. Is it correct?